# Why some profile image enlarge on mouse hover?

Tags: support, profile-picture, user-card

When passing the mouse over the image of users in a normal question page, some images become bigger and are shown some infos of the user.

Why it isn't so for all users?

How can I activate this on my profile?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a privilege you have as an established user at 1000 rep. See the related page for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

Comment: Thanks! So it requires 1000 rep and at least 28 characters in the "About Me" section.

Comment: Yes, exactly @T30.